# Noise on power line when charging USB

Tags: usb, audio, noise

For the starter:

I have build device that use DTMF code to control LED light the device can be both power from USB charger or integrated on the board PoE module. The power is also used to power table or phone over USB that generates DTMF code.

So now to the point: One of the tablets creates noise in the power line when charging. And the specific of the noise disrupts DTMF decoder. You can see the noise in the spectrum below.

I have try BLM21PG221SN1 as suggested in this document: 
http://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/emc/emifil/c35e.ashx Unfortunately it did not help.

Also I have try suggestions from this document http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_146_USB_Hardware_Design_Guidelines_for_FTDI_ICs.pdf . It also did not help :/

Any idea how I can suppress that noise ? I need 1A to go to the tablet.

[image: Spectrum of the 5+ GND when charging the table]

Comment: Can you show us what is going on your power line? I mean oscillogram of voltage between +5V and GND.

Comment: @Kamil Unfortunately the only one I have right now is from Audio card I will have the access to scope tomorrow.

Comment: I have no clue if it might help,  but i know the atmel brand microcontroller use a simple inductor capacitor pair between analog and digital ground to decouple the noise sensitive analog section from the noisy digital side.

Answer (score 1):

Check voltage on your power supply when tablet is charging. Some phone/tablet chargers are bad quality/bad design and voltage at "nominal current" drops really low (I have 2.5A charger that drops to 4.5V at 2A).

In USB specyfication voltage tolerance is something like 4.5V if I'm not mistaken, so it does the job and, you can charge tablet or phone, but power line is one big noise and you can't use it for anything else.

You can try something like this:

[image]

I use [SS12](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88746/ss12.pdf) or similar shottky diode with low voltage drop. If power supply is 5V - dropping 0.1 or 0.2V on diode is usually not a problem for most 5V devices even if your power supply voltage drops to 4.8V under load.

You can use lower or higher capacitor value - it depends on current required by "noise free" power line.

Comment: The idea look good but It would be very hard to mode my board. However do you think I can just put the diode on the line to the table ?

Comment: Table or tablet?

Comment: Usb spec is +/- 5% or 0.25 V

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the DTMF decoder from 3.3 volts? If so, you should use a low drop-out linear regulator (LDO) to make a smooth 3.3 volt power supply to your DTMF decoder circuit from the noisy 5 volt USB power.

Comment: Unfortunately it 5V only.